# Django/Python - Help moving is_authenticated and user == model.user to view

Tags: python, django, django-templates

First off, sorry if I am not clear on what I'm trying to do or if I don't give enough info, I'm still relatively new to Django/Python.

I currently have a view that renders something like a blog post:

```
class SingleCharacter(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Character

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SingleCharacter, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

And, in the template for this view, I have a template tag that checks if the user is authenticated AND the owner of the post:

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated and user == character.user %}
```

However, I'm currently in the process of incorporating xhtml2pdf into my project and this method of securing the post to only the user who created it is causing some issues.

I'm wondering if it's possible to move the user.is_authenticated and user == character.user into the view instead of a template tag, and if so can i do it with a simple if statment, something like this?

```
class SingleCharacter(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Character
    if user.is_authenticated and user == character.user:
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          context = super(SingleCharacter, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
          return context
    else:
      <I'll include some redirect to a 404 page>
```

I'm trying to see if there's another way to do it, but I thought I'd throw this out here to the more experienced people in hopes of figuring it out.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can create a user authentification logic and make a small function which returns True if the user is authentic, False otherwise. Add this as a decorator. This makes the code reusable :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `get` method of the DetailView and handle the logic there:

```
class SingleCharacter(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Character

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user == self.object.user:
            context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
            return self.render_to_response(context)
        else:
            # redirect
```